# Form is not submitting data via POST or GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I've recently been working on a website's user registration system and I just finished the front end, it is using parsleyjs to validate the values in the form.

The problem I have is when the form is submitted no values are passed, is there any reason for this happening?

**Form Code**

```
<form role="form" method="get" data-validate="parsley" id="register" action="register/2/">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userFirstName">Frist Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userFirstName" placeholder="John" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userLastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userLastName" placeholder="Newman" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="NewJohn101" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" data-usernamecheck="true">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userEmail">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" placeholder="Email" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-type="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userPasswordRetype">Re-Type Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPasswordRetype" placeholder="Re-Type Password" data-required="true" data-equalto="#userPassword" data-trigger="change">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: where is js/jQuery in this code? Post that too.

Comment: You didn't set the `name` attributes of any of your inputs. That is required.

Comment: I believe that it is time for me to take a break today, I can't believe that was my only problem.

Comment: Haha it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `POST` and `GET` assign values to keys that are equivalent to the `name` attribute of your inputs. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test">
```

Will build the array

```
"test" => $_GET["input1"]
```

No name attribute. No array.

Comment: Yes, form values are accessible with the name attribute, if you haven't assigned, then how are you getting your values?